# python: How do I avoid NonImplentedError if I just import instead of run the module?

Tags: python, exception, import

I have an interface-like function implemented this way:

```
# File: parsers.py
class BaseParser(object):
    '''Interface class'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.content

    def Parse(self):
        """The interface, not implemented"""

        raise NotImplementedError('{}.Parse()'.format(inspect.stack()[0][3]))

class SimpleParser(BaseParser):
    '''Implementation class'''
    def __init__(self):
        BaseParser.__init__(self)

    def Parse(self):
        # Do real work
```

Now when I import this module, I get NotImplementedError right away so I can't use SimpleParser.
How could I use this exception idiom and still be able to use it?

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't get it if the module you import doesn't run tests.

Comment: if you are getting a NotImplementedError right away, then you aren't showing us all of your code. The code you've posted, run with `import parser` in the same directory as `parser.py` and with a `pass` in SimpleParser.Parse, doesn't raise any error.

Answer (score 6):

Your indentation is goofed, mixing spaces and tabs. Use `python -tt` to verify.

Comment: Also methods should be uncapitalised... http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables